# ES6 export default function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

can I export more than one function per file ?
it seems like when I do that , the second function ovverides the first one ,

example : 
in `my index.js` file :

```
export default function aFnt(){
    console.log("function a");
}
export default function bFnt(){
    console.log("function b");
}
```

then when I import it in my file :

```
import aFnt from "./index";

console.log("aFnt : ",aFnt);
```

the result of the console.log is bFnt

what exactly is the case here ? do I have to create a new file per function ? that is not very practical , any solution or workaround ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[madox2's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741871/madox2) answer totally works if you want to import named functions.

If you still want to import the default, there's another technique:

```
function a() {}

function b() {}

export default { a, b }
```

and when you import:

```
import myObject from './index.js';

myObject.a(); // function a
myObject.b(); // function b
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: nice approach thanks bobby , is there any difference ?

Comment: It is much preferred if you are building out a module with many functions

Comment: Thanks for accepting! I've many times seen some nastiness with `{ myCoolFunction, myOtherCoolFunction, mySuperDuperCoolFunction } from './index';` which can get pretty unwieldy

Comment: Exporting an object as your default is an antipattern in ES6. If you need an object with the exports, you should use named exports and do `import * as myObject from './index.js';`. It accomplishes the same goal but works better with tools that do static analysis and dead code elimination.

Comment: @loganfsmyth is right. This answer should not be accepted. When you bundle all your functions into one default export object like this code is doing, you are forcing the importer to import *all* functions... making his bundle much bigger than needed. You should only use default export when you have only 1 function in the first place. Otherwise use named export so people can grab just the function they need.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports) instead of default:

```
export function aFnt(){
    console.log("function a");
}
export function bFnt(){
    console.log("function b");
}
```

and import it like:

```
import {aFnt, bFnt} from "./index";
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. If you bundle all your functions in a single object you force the importer to bundle all these functions even when he needs only one. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: im wondering why export bFont = () => { } doesnt work but function bFont() { } does

Comment: @chitgoks you are missing `const` keyword - `export const bFont = () => { }`. Then it works

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of ways to export and import objects/functions

```
export function first() {}
export function second() {}
```

in other file

```
import { first, second} from './somepath/somefile/';
```

if you want to use default, in general if there is only one export in a file it should be a default export. but if you for some reasons want two functions as default then you have to club them as a object and export that object as default

```
function first() {}
function second() {}
const funcs= {"first":first,"second":second}
export default funcs;
```

in other file

```
import funcs from './somepath/somefile/';
funcs.first();funs.second();
```

this should be it.