# Common JS - Is it possible to require a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have a self-invoking function setup in webpack and and using common JS to require some packages:

```
(function() {
    var $ = require("jquery");

//...my function
})();
```

I can pull in jquery not problem but I now have another function I need to pull in across several modules. Is it possible using require or similar to import a function? IE:

```
var getAPIObj = require('../../Project/js/getAPIObj');
```

Comment: Yes, [it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541864/es6-export-default-function), it depends on how this function is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible , for that you need to export the function or module.You can learn more about [**modules**](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

someFile.js

```
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
//otherFile.js
import { square } from 'someFile';
```